# Combine VLOOKUP with filter

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm doing a weight loss challenge with ~30 friends and am wanting to make a sheet to track where everyone is at. I've set up a simple two question survey for people to answer. The output of the survey for each weigh in is in 3 columns in a spreadsheet:

A                       B.            C
Timestamp.     Name.    Weight

What I am trying to do is find the latest timestamp for each name and then pull in the value from column C that is put in from that timestamp. This would be pulled into a separate sheet in the book with 2 columns - name and latest weight.

I've got it running in Google Sheets. I've searched and tried every formula I've seen listed for a somewhat similar use case but can't find one that works.

Comment: Does this work:
Order by timestamp desc, then use vlookup (be sure to include the final variable so that the lookup is exact, not approximate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One two-step solution is to use a UNIQUE formula to get a list of names:

`=UNIQUE(Sheet1!B2:B)`

Then this formula will pull through the most recent weight value:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A,SORT({Sheet1!B:C,Sheet1!A:A},3,0),2,0)))`

You can see it working in this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10REe4a1KnpvjizoC8AqLT27ZS-PcSx9DTH350EJLZ-s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. If you don't want the timestamp column, you can hide the column.

```
=FILTER( Sheet1!A:C , MATCH(Sheet1!A:A ,QUERY( Sheet1!A:C , "select max(A) group by B" ) , FALSE ) )
```